# Include root object with jackson in springboot deserializer

Tags: java, jackson, spring-boot, json-deserialization

How can I include the objeto root in my jackson deserializer with spring-boot?

i try to put in application.properties

```
spring.jackson.deserialization.UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE=true
```

i try using one configurator

```
@Configuration
public class JacksonConfig {

    @Bean
    public Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder jacksonBuilder() {
        Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder builder = new Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder();
        builder.featuresToEnable(DeserializationFeature.UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE);
        builder.indentOutput(true).dateFormat(new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"));
        builder.indentOutput(true);
        return builder;
    }

}
```

And i put in my classe the annotation

```
@JsonRootName("contato")
public class TbContato extends EntityBase {
```

but dont work i got this return:

```
{
  "cdContato": 12,
  "dtContato": "03/08/2015 16:04:43",
  "cdUsuario": null,
  "nmParte": "Fabio Ebner",
  "nmEmailParte": "fabioebner@gmail.com",
  "nmAssunto": "Assuntttoooo",
  "dsMensagem": "mensagem nessa porra aqui",
  "dtResposta": null,
  "dsResposta": null,
  "cdUsuarioResposta": null,
  "nmUsuarioResposta": null
}
```

without the root.

Comment: @OP did you ever get around this problem? I am also struggling currently with the same.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because you're serializing not deserializing. Try using

```
spring.jackson.serialization.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE=true
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to have parameterized generic root-wrapper class like this:

```
package com.example.wrappedResponse.model;

public class ResponseWrapper<T> {
    private T contato;

    public ResponseWrapper(T contato) {
        this.contato = contato;
    }

    public T getContato() {
        return response;
    }

    public void setContato(T contato) {
        this.contato = contato;
    }
}
```

and then in a controller wrap the entity with that type.

```
package com.example.wrappedResponse.controller;

import com.example.wrappedResponse.model.EntityBase;    
import com.example.wrappedResponse.model.ResponseWrapper;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;

@RestController
class EntityWrappingController {

    @GetMapping("/get/wrapped/base/entity")
    public ResponseWrapper<EntityBase> status() {
        EntityBase entityToWrap;
        // get you entity from application …

        return new ResponseWrapper<>(entityToWrap);
    }
}
```

That makes sense if you want to have more than one response wrap with the same key.