# Json response in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, jackson, jsonresponse

I am using spring boot, while returning the object as JSON response I am getting something like this below.

```
{
  "userId": "e340f903-033f-45ba-91c0-798678a71510",
  "firstName": "Varun",
  "lastName": "Sabkanln",
  "reputationCount": 0
}
```

what I want, is a key assigned to this response.

```
{ 
 "profile":{
            "userId": "e340f903-033f-45ba-91c0-798678a71510",
            "firstName": "Varun",
            "lastName": "Sabkanln",
             "reputationCount": 0
           }
}
```

This class is as follows.

```
public class UserProfileDao {

    private String userId;

    private String firstName;

    private String lastName;

    private int reputationCount;
 }
```

Is there any jackson annotation for this or any other simpler way with less code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Include root object with jackson in springboot deserializer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31794945/include-root-object-with-jackson-in-springboot-deserializer)

Answer (score 1):

did you try

```
public class profile {
    private UserProfileDao userProfileDao;
    //some getters and some setters.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create another POJO like this and return an object of this class

```
public class Profile {
    private UserProfileDao profile;
    //getters and setters.
}
```

Other way is to use `@JsonRootName` annotation

```
@JsonRootName(value = "profile")
public class UserProfileDao {

    private String userId;

    private String firstName;

    private String lastName;

    private int reputationCount;
 }
```